# Opening hours in Maastricht for Ascension

Tags: netherlands, public-holidays, opening-hours, maastricht

I wanted to make a one-day trip to Maastricht tomorrow, but it's Ascension day. Are shops and cafes opened during this holiday?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [tourist association](http://vvvmaastricht.nl/shoppen/openingstijden.html)

> Tijdens Hemelvaartsdag (29 mei 2014) zijn de winkels in het centrum geopend van 12.00 tot 17.00/18.00 uur.

In English it reads that the shops in the city centre are open from 12:00-17:00/18:00. The 1st of June the shops will be closed. For cafes I would be highly surprised if they are closed, so I assume they will be open as well.